# Meromorphic functions on upper half plane and infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory, modular-forms, meromorphic-functions

Is the set of all meromorphic functions on the upper half plane which they are also meromorphic at infinity, a field?

I am trying to show that the set of all modular functions for $Sl_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a field. But, I want to know that is it necessary to have that for all element $\gamma$ in $Sl_2(\mathbb{Z})$, for all $z\in H$, $f(\gamma z)=f(z)$?

Comment: Yes, it is a field.

Comment: Isn't that obvious that it is a ring and that $1/f$ being meromorphic it is a field ? $f(\gamma z) = f(z)$ in the sense of meromorphic functions ie. as functions $H\to \Bbb{C}\cup \infty$